# use dplyr to get values of a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to have dplyr return a character vector instead of a data frame. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
#example data frame 
df <- data.frame( x=c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'), 
                  y=c('a','a','b','b','c','c','d','d'),
                  z=c('a','a','a','a','a','a','d','d'),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


#desired output
unique(df$z)
[1] "a" "d"

#dplys's output
df %>% 
  select(z) %>%
  unique() 

z
1 a
7 d
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   select(z) %>%
   unique() %>% 
   .$z
#[1] "a" "d"
```

Or using `magrittr`

```
library(magrittr)
df %>%
  select(z) %>%
  unique() %>%
  use_series(z)
#[1] "a" "d"
```

Comment: thanks @akrun the `use_series` is just what the doctor ordered

Comment: @akrun, let's assume that `z` is string column name e.g. `z <- "x"` - how can I subset value then?

Comment: @Taz You can use `select_at` `df %>% select_at(z)` or evaluate `df %>% select(!! z)`

Comment: @akrun I will get 1x1 data frame - not value of that 1x1 dataframe. But I have already figured it out: 
`df %>% select(z) %>%  unique() %>%  use_series(z) %>%  .[[1]]`

Comment: @Taz I thought you wanted to know how to select it\